# Changing theme of spinner in android

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, layout-inflater

I have a spinner in my layout and want to customize its style in API's level pre- and post-Lollipop.

I've used following style for style-v23.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and this is bg_spinner file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="0.33dp" android:color="#0fb1fa" />

                <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:right="5dp">

            <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_down" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>

</item>

</selector>
```

But when I run the program in API level 23, it returns below error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

However, it works correctly in android other API levels as expected.
Is there anyone to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where you reference `SpinnerTheme` style, please post the code?

Comment: It's the first code above!

Comment: Everything is correct. Problem must be in your src attribute. I used the android drawable file `android:src="@drawable/ic_close_light"` and worked fine. Change the src drawable and run again.

Comment: It's correct. Post as Answer so that I can accept it. But what's the problem with this xml file?

Comment: @Mahdia posted as answer. you must use image drawable for `src` not xml drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct. Problem should be in your src attribute. I used the android drawable file `android:src="@drawable/ic_close_light"` and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Spinner tag in xml...

```
style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
```

Comment: I've done this and I got the error because of this line. If I delete this line there is no change in style and no error.

Comment: parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown" write this line in your style in replace of parent="AppTheme"

Comment: Thanks but the same error. I think the problem is in bg_spinner file.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

add this spinner in your styles.xml file

```
 <style name="spinnerStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
 </style>
```

put this line in your application theme

```
  <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinnerStyle</item>
```

create xml file in drawable folder spinner_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="your color"
                        />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item>
            <bitmap
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:src="your dropdown image"/>
        </item>

    </layer-list>

</item>

</selector>
```